# Read assembly MethodBody, parse its Name in a ListBox and its IL in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, dnlib

I have a WPF `MainWindow` Form with a `ListBox` and a `TextBox` that looks like this:

> [image: Figure A. WPF MainWindow with Sample Text.]
>   <sub>Figure A. WPF MainWindow with Sample Text.</sub>

Now, the `Load Assembly...` *OnClick* button event allows me to select a .NET Assembly and load it up using [DnLib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib)

Then, if I want to display the Methods bodies I would do it like so:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);
                foreach (Module mod in asm.GetModules())
                {
                    foreach (Type types in mod.GetTypes())
                    {
                        foreach (MethodInfo mdInfo in types.GetMethods())
                        {
                            listBox.Items.Add(mdInfo.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This adds each found Method name to the `ListBox` on the left, resulting like so:

> [image: Figure B. Showing the ListBox Filled with Methods Names]
>   <sub>Figure B. Showing the ListBox Filled with Methods Names</sub>

Now the trick part, I would like to for whichever method I select from the `ListBox` to display its respective MethodBody IL on the `TextBox`

How can I achieve such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### «Phew!» Finally Solved it!

Here's the solution for whoever tries to do the same thing in the future.

> Make an instance of 'List' and then iterate through the methods and assign the names to such list, then whenever your `SelectedItem` *index* value changes, I can simply call `GetMethodBodyByName` and then I can surely solve this issue

Here's how to implement the function `GetMethodBodyByName`:

```
public string GetMethodBodyByName(string methodName)
    {
        ModuleDefMD md = ModuleDefMD.Load(filename);
        foreach (TypeDef type in md.Types)
        {
            foreach (MethodDef method in type.Methods)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < type.Methods.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (method.HasBody)
                    {
                        if (method.Name == methodName)
                        {
                            var instr = method.Body.Instructions;
                            return String.Join("\r\n", instr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

> The idea is that 'GetMethodBodyByName' will receive the method name as a parameter, then it will iterate through methods and see if a method matches the given name, then if found, the function will just simply iterate through that method and output the method's body.

Here's how my `ListBox_SelectedItemChanged` event looks like:

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "";
        textBox.Text = GetMethodBodyByName(method[listBox.SelectedIndex].Name);
    }
```

#### That's All Folks!

***Note: Be careful when doing this approach as if when you request names, different methods can have the same names. But that's a cake for another day, I'm done for now! take care bye-bye!***

---

#### Working our way up for the Ultimate Solution!

The WPF MainWindow Forms carry with themselves two little useful properties, they are: `Tag` and `Content`, the idea is the following one:

> With the `Tag` and `Content` Property we can assign any values to it that later it can be retrieved `On-The-Fly` without having to depend on Methods names specifically for this task.

So you would instead of looping each method and get its name respectively you can just do the way I did:

> Iterate through the Method, and assign its body to the `Tag` property, and its name to the `Content` property, as this last property is the one that handles the actual `Title` property, so disregarding anything you do with the method in the future and even if it had the same name of another one, it will work no matter what.

**How Can We Implement It?**

Simply:

```
<...>
// Inside Method Body iteration routine...
<...>

var instr = mdInfo.Body.Instructions;

                        // Allocate in a new `ListBoxItem` each method and add it to the current listbox with their
                        // ... respective Tag and Content information... // Many Thanks Kao :D
                        newItem = new ListBoxItem();
                        newItem.Content = mdInfo.Name;
                        newItem.Tag = string.Join("\r\n", instr);

                        method.Add(mdInfo);
                        listBox.Items.Add(newItem);
```

Then on your `SelectedItem` Index-Value-Changed Event put this:

```
            MSILTextBox.Clear();
            // Retrieve them given the selected index...
            // ... the returned value will be the Tag content of the ...
            // ... previously saved item.
            string getTag= ((ListBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
            MSILTextBox.Text = getTag;
```